# Should I use the same OpenPGP keys in certificates used to provision the YubiKey PIV slots?

Tags: smartcard, openpgp, yubikey

I know PIV and OpenPGP are separate standards and independent applications in the YubiKey, but for newcomers like me they look very similar with their signing, encryption and authentication keys, use cases, etc.

After setting up my YubiKey with OpenPGP keys I'm wondering: is it advisable, useful and/or secure to load the PIV slots with certificates issued for the same keys used for OpenPGP?

Comment: You could potentially create separate GPG subkeys for the same key, and load them in each separate slot.

Comment: I'm already creating three separate subkeys (signing, encryption and authentication) and loading them on each OpenPGP slots. What I meant was issuing certificates for those same three keys and load them on the PIV slots. So no matter if I sign a message through OpenPGP or PIV, the signing key would be the same and hence the signature.